# Unable to click the radio button in the goibibo site because of every radio button is having may be same elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My **code**:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Eclipse1\\Selenium\\SeleniumBasic\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/flights/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Round trip']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']")).sendKeys("Coimbatore");
Thread.sleep(1500);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='react-autosuggest-1']/li[1]")).click();
//or8
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='react-autosuggest-1']/li[@id='react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--0']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputDest']")).sendKeys("Bangalore");
Thread.sleep(1000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='react-autosuggest-1']/li[1]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='inputSrch curPointFlt ' and @placeholder='Departure']")).click();

Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Day' and @aria-label='Mon Feb 25 2019']")).click();

Thread.sleep(2000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='DayPicker-Day' and @aria-label='Thu Feb 28 2019']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dF whiteBg fl col-sm-5 justifyBetween ht45 alignItemsCenter brdrTpBtmRt curPointFlt width20']")).click();

Thread.sleep(1000);
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='fl plusSpin brdrTpBtmRt'  and @id='adultPaxPlus']")).click();
}

Select s=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='custSelect width100 whiteBg padTB5 padLR10']")));

s.selectByValue("B");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='Search']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='javascript:void(0);' and @id='sortByPriceOnw']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='fl posAbs icon-close1 ico17 curPoint fb whiteBg closePers black']")).click();
System.out.println("hi");
Thread.sleep(1500);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='javascript:void(0);' and @id='sortByPriceRet']")).click();

/*Thread.sleep(1000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='we_close']")).click();*/
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='control__indicator'])[2]")).click();
```

**Exception:**

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (648, 603). Other element would receive the click: 
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.119)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: 'SAISHANMUKHAVAR', ip: '192.168.137.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b54..., userDataDir: C:\Users\gsais\AppData\Loca...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60971}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 72.0.3626.119, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 8279839ce42d641ca8e2c7bdefc6ab07
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at GoIbiboCLass.main(GoIbiboCLass.java:70)

Comment: Some steps to debug this would be:

1. figure out what element Selenium is trying to click when the error message occurs (It will be whatever is on line 70 per the error message you've provided

2. Find the "Other element would receive the click"

At this point it may be obvious how to resolve the problem.  If the "other element" is disappearing after some amount of time, there are methods to wait for this before clicking.  If the other element will not go away after some time then you have a different discussion because that would make for a very strange application.

Comment: I have tried everything but its not working

Comment: What do you mean? Where in the debug steps is it "not working"?  Were you unable to identify the "other element that could receive the click"?  Not following.

Comment: Yaa i am unable to identify the other element which is recieving the click

Comment: I've noticed you error is occurring on line 70, but the code you've uploaded is only 56 lines long.  Could you upload the entire file, or at least indicate which line is number 70?